# Can a json contain same key value?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I take the content of two table performing a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2
     ON table1.code = table2.code
```

Now the `table1` have a structure like this:

```
|CODE|Info|Created          |Modified
|R789|Home|21/03/2016 10:00 |21/03/2016 15:00
```

and `table2`:

```
|CODE|Description|Created       |Modified
|R789|Testing| 21/03/2016 10:05 | 21/03/2016  18:10
```

Now the problem is that the query return this result:

```
"Code":"RB01",
"Info":Home,
"Created":"21/03/2016 10:05",
"Modified":"21/03/2016 18:10",
"Description":"Testing"
```

How you can see I have `created`and `modified` that is identical in the two tables. So the query discard the `created` and `modified` of `table1`.. this is a problem for me, how can I avoid this situation?

Comment: What do they two tables represent? What is the desired result?

Comment: @showdev the `table1` is a list of item. The `table2` contains the description of each item, note that the second table can have multiple code as R789... Now I want return all the fields of the two tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [AS keyword to create an alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm140092775273264) for the column name. Consider this:

```
SELECT t1.CODE, t1.Info, t1.Created AS t1Created, t1.Modified AS t1Modified, t2.Description, t2.Created AS t2Created, t2.Modified AS t2Modified
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CODE = t2.CODE
```

This will return

```
"Code":"RB01",
"Info":Home,
"t1Created":"21/03/2016 10:00",
"t1Modified":"21/03/2016 15:00",
"Description":"Testing",
"t2Created":"21/03/2016 10:05",
"t2Modified":"21/03/2016 18:10",
```

Comment: So if I have thousands fields my query will be of 100 rows?

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes no sense. How many fields there are has no correlation on the number of rows in a table.

Comment: Nope, I'm explained bad. I mean, instead of doing this `SELECT t1.CODE, t1.Info, t1.Created AS t1Created, t1.Modified AS t1Modified` is possible do this: `SELECT * FROM table1` and achieve the same result?

Comment: @Sandokan no, it's not possible. You have to list the columns out so you can apply an alias using `AS`.

Comment: uhmm.. your solution fix the problem I know, but I have a lot of fields.. So I need to change the name of the `table2` fields? There is no other solutions?

Comment: @Sandokan No, there is no other solution.